# Angular 4 Error: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material in my Angular 4 app. When I try to use the `MatSnackBar` in the `ngAfterViewInit()`, I am facing an error as:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:
>   'visible-bottom'.It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

I have used the `ChangeDetectorRef` to detect the changes, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I have been working on:

```
   constructor(private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar, private router: Router, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

   ngOnInit() {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    let snackBarRef = this.matSnackBar.open('Redirecting to dashboard..', 'Cancel', {
      duration: 10000
    });

    snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Cancelled");
    });


    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try moving `this.cdr.detectChanges();` inside the `onAction().subscribe(() => {});`

Comment: @AmitChigadani That doesn't work!

Comment: Try to create a working plunker to replicate the error. Provided code won't help much.

Answer (score 4):

One potential but crude solution is to use setTimeout -

```
let snackBarRef;
setTimeout(() => {
    snackBarRef = this.matSnackBar.open('Redirecting to dashboard..', 'Cancel', {
      duration: 10000
    });
});
```

please refer https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6158 for more information.

Comment: I already did that. It works, but I am looking for Angular way of detecting those changes.

Comment: @ProtonStarlight, I tried to find out the ways out of interest, I found 2 potential approaches which are as follows -
1. To use ngAfterContentInit instead of ngAfterViewInit, please refer - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#no-unidirectional-flow-worries-with-aftercontent
2. To use detach method of ChangeDetectorRef before/in combination with detectChanges method.
Please note I have not used these personally but I think those can be helpful.

Comment: @ProtonStarlight, Did you get a chance to check my comment?

Comment: but isn't `AfterContentInit` too early to initialize a visual element where the view doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 4):

Try to move snackbar in your constructor:

```
constructor(private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar, private router: Router, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  let snackBarRef = this.matSnackBar.open('Redirecting to dashboard..', 'Cancel', {
    duration: 10000
  });
  snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Cancelled");
  });
}
```